# Bing Ajax V8 DirectionsManager addWayPoint with custom text

Tags: bing-maps

In V7 I could create a Pushpin with custom text: value in the PushpinOptions, then create a Waypoint with the Location and Pushpin, then add the Waypoint with DirectionsManager.addWayPoint.

V8 doesn't appear to have a Waypoint constructor that accepts a Pushpin.  How to add Waypoints with custom text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directions manager has been changed significantly in V8. In V7 it was over engineered with many duplicate functionalities and majority of these features were used by a very small number of apps. In this case, the option to customize waypoints, is something that wasn't originally in the new directions manager, but only due to the complexity of supporting this as directions are rendered completely differently from standard shapes. That said, this has been added to the experimental branch of V8 recently. You can customize the waypoints by using the waypointPushpinOptions, firstWaypointPushpinOptions, lastWaypointPushpinOptions properties of the DirectionsRenderOptions.

Comment: When will `waypointPushpinOptions` be released? I can only access this feature by using the experimental branch.

Comment: This was released a couple weeks ago, but doesn't yet support the visible option in the main release branch.